# Find All Positive Pairs of $(\alpha,\beta)$ Such that $\,\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_k}{n^{\alpha}}=\beta$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, limits

Consider the following sequence

$(a_n)=(1,1,2,1,2,3,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,5,1,...)$

Find all pairs of $(\alpha,\beta)$ of positive number such that $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\dfrac{\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_k}{n^{\alpha}}=\beta.$$

This is really a heart breaking question for me.

Comment: Note that if a pair does exist, then it must be the only one. This is because if $S_n\approx \beta_1 n^{\alpha_1}\approx \beta_2 n^{\alpha_2}$ then $(\alpha_1,\beta_1)=(\alpha_2,\beta_2)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let: $N_n=\binom{n+1}{2}$(then $a_{N_n}$ is the first appearance of number $n$ in the sequence) and consider limit of the subsequence: 
$$
\begin{align}
b_{N_n}=\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{N_n}a_k}{N_n^\alpha}&=\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n}1+2+..+k}{\binom{n+1}{2}^\alpha}\\
&=\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n}\binom{k+1}{2}}{\binom{n+1}{2}^\alpha}\\
&=\frac{\binom{n+2}{2}}{\binom{n+1}{2}^\alpha}\\
&=\frac{\frac16n^3(1+\frac2n)(1+\frac1n)}{(\frac12)^\alpha n^{2\alpha}(1+\frac1n)^\alpha}
\end{align}
$$ We can see that $\lim_{n\to \infty}b_{N_n}$ is positive and finite if and only if $\alpha=\frac32$. In this case the limit is equal to $\beta=\frac{\sqrt2}3$. So, this pair $(\alpha,\beta)=(\frac32,\frac{\sqrt2}3)$ is the only candidate for solution. We will show convergence of the original sequence for these values of $\alpha$ and $\beta$. Let $N$ be a positive integer in $[N_n+1,N_{n+1}]$, i.e., $N = N_n+m$ for some $1 \le m \le n+1$. Then we have:
$$b_N=\frac{\binom{n+2}{3}+\binom{m+1}{2}}{(m+\binom{n+1}{2})^{\frac32}}$$ whih
can be estimated by:  $$\frac{\binom{n+2}{3}}{(n+\binom{n+1}{2})^{\frac32 }}\le b_N \le \frac{\binom{n+2}{3}+\binom{n+1}{2}}{\binom{n+1}{2}^{\frac32}}$$ Since both bounds convergence to $\frac{\sqrt2}3$ the sequence $b_N$ has the same limit and we are done.

Answer (score 1):

Observe that
$$
a_1+\cdots+a_{n(n+1)/2}=\frac{n(n+1)(n+2)}{6},
$$
and if $\dfrac{n(n-1)}{2}<k<\dfrac{n(n+1)}{2}$, then
$$
\frac{n(n^2-1)}{6}<a_k<\frac{n(n+1)(n+2)}{6}.
$$
Now,
$$
\dfrac{\sum_{k=1}^{\frac{n(n+1)}{2}}a_k}{\left(\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\right)^\alpha}=
\frac{\dfrac{n(n+1)(n+2)}{6}}{\left(\dfrac{n(n+1)}{2}\right)^\alpha}.
$$
So, for $\alpha<3/2$, then $\beta=\infty$, for $\alpha>3/2$, then $\beta=0$ and $\alpha=3/2$, then
$$
\beta=\frac{2^{1/2}}{3}.
$$